# How to test ETags in Spring API with SOAPui?

Tags: java, soapui, etag, spring-rest

I have tried to configure the ETags in my Spring REST API. As far as I understand, I just needed to add a filter, which with jetty server looks like:

```
servletContextHandler.addFilter(new FilterHolder( 
    new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter()) , "/*", EnumSet.allOf( DispatcherType.class ));
```

Then I started my SOApui and makde a request with a `Etag` header. When I got a responce, I resent the request with the `If-None-Match` header.

I supposed to receive an empty responce with 304 status code, but instead of this the responce was full, as if there is not any ETag thing at all.

Should I add something to Spring-Etag configuration? should I set something in SOAPui request?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I wanted to use both ETag and Spring Security. The last switches somehow the first off if by configuration the following line is not added:

```
http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
```